# Grouping on an expression (and possible HAVE)

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query, which I rewrote as a 'simple' example below.

The expression `CONVERT(int, RTRIM(' ' + UPPER(CONVERT(char, a+b))))/c` is just a weird example of a complex function.

I am questioning myself:
 Why do I have to put this *complex* expression 3 times in my query?

```
DROP TABLE #TEMP
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (a int, b int, c int)

INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES( 1,1,1)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES( 1,1,2)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES( 1,1,3)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES( 1,2,1)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES( 1,2,2)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES( 1,2,3)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES( 2,1,1)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES( 2,1,2)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES( 2,1,3)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES( 2,2,1)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES( 2,2,2)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES( 2,2,3)



SELECT 
    a,
    b,
    CONVERT(int, RTRIM(' ' + UPPER(CONVERT(char, a+b))))/c as d
from #TEMP
GROUP BY a, b, CONVERT(int, RTRIM(' ' + UPPER(CONVERT(char, a+b))))/c
HAVING CONVERT(int, RTRIM(' ' + UPPER(CONVERT(char, a+b))))/c >= 0
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

The question is mainly for using in SQL Server, but answers for other database management systems are welcome too.

Comment: If you ask why you can't use a column alias in the GROUP BY and HAVING clauses, then the answer is that the column alias is done *after* those operations. Meaning that column alias doesn't exist at the "time" the  GROUP BY and HAVING work with the data. And, as suggested, you can handle this using a tabular subquery having your expression. See for instance this on logical query processing: https://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/60250/logical-query-processing-sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to.  You can just rewrite it to CTE/inline view , and refer by alias :

```
SELECT t.* FROM 
(
SELECT 
    a,
    b,
    CONVERT(int, RTRIM(' ' + UPPER(CONVERT(char, a+b))))/c as d
from #TEMP
)t
GROUP BY a,b,d
HAVING d > 0 
ORDER BY 3 ;
```

or

```
WITH cte1 AS 
(
SELECT 
    a,
    b,
    CONVERT(int, RTRIM(' ' + UPPER(CONVERT(char, a+b))))/c as d
from #TEMP
)
select t.* 
from cte1 t
group by t.a,t.b,t.d 
having t.d > 0 
order by 3;
```

Also, there is no need for  `GROUP BY`( and `HAVING` can be replaced by `WHERE`)  in this particular case - `SELECT DISTINCT` will do the job.

Comment: " in this particular case".... my query was just an example, so this remark does not count ;)

Comment: But, yes, on could do it the way you proposed. But maybe it's a bit confusing to put this extra  syntax for an easy job... (aliasing an expression once, and referring it multiple times seems easier!)

Comment: @Luuk:  Some RDBMS allow you do that . For instance, in mysql  you can use alias in `having` and `group by`, in postgres  - only in `group by `. Oracle works the same as SQLServer from that perspective.   Inline view approach(#1) will work everywhere.